# asio c++ get two threads running data from two sources asynchronously

Tags: c++, asio

I am building a programme with C++ in which I want to run "two threads looking at two sources for data asynchronously". I do not know if this is possible or not. I have so far been able to read data from one source with a single thread. I want to read data from two threads asynchronously. Has anyone done something like this in the past that can point me in the right direction? I am using the asio C++ standalone version. Or is this something that is just not possible?
I will really appreciate you advice.

This is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include <asio/ts/internet.hpp>

std::vector<char> vBuffer(2 * 1024);

void getData1(asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket1)
{
    socket1.async_read_some(asio::buffer(vBuffer.data(), vBuffer.size()),
        [&](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "\n\nRead " << length << " bytes\n\n";

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    std::cout << vBuffer[i];

                getData1(socket1);
            }
        }
    );
}

//Make it read from two sources
void getData2(asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket1)
{
    socket1.async_read_some(asio::buffer(vBuffer.data(), vBuffer.size()),
        [&](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "\n\nRead " << length << " bytes\n\n";

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    std::cout << vBuffer[i];

                getData2(socket1);
            }
        }
    );
}



int main() {

    asio::error_code ec;

    asio::io_context context1;

    asio::io_context context2;  //This to read data fron another source, eg another ip address and port

    //Allow asio to do some fake tasks so that the context doesn't finish
    asio::io_context::work idleWork(context1);

    //Start the context
    std::thread thrContext = std::thread([&]() {context1.run(); });

    std::thread thrContext2 = std::thread([&]() {context2.run();});

    //Get the address of somewhere we wish to connect to
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("51.38.81.49", ec), 80);  //ip exists
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint2(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1", ec), 80);  //ip exists

    //Create a socket the, the context will deliver the implementation
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket1(context1);

    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket2(context2);

    //Tell the socket to connect to the first address specified
    socket1.connect(endpoint, ec);

    //Tell the socket to connect to the second address specified
    socket2.connect(endpoint2, ec);


    //Here we can check the error code to see if it was successful
    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Connected successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to address:\n" << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }


    //Here we check if socket is open or not with an if statement
    if (socket1.is_open())
    {
        getData1(socket1); //Here we are calling our function as against calling it at the buttom part

        std::string sRequest =
            "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host: example.com\r\n\r\n";

        socket1.write_some(asio::buffer(sRequest.data(), sRequest.size()), ec);

        //Stop programme from exiting prematurely
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i guess you tried just doing it? what happened when you just did it?

Comment: To be clearer, what exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the code that I am working with to the original post by editing it.

Comment: I wonder why you even need two threads to do this

Comment: I am open to suggestions on this. Do you know of another way to achieve this? My approach to it so far might be wrong.